# How can i popup calendar only on image click but not on Textbox focus

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I use the Jquery from here [JQUERY](http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html) i tried all possible cases as per shown in the document for not popping-up the calendar on `textbox` but i could not stop it. So can any one help me on  this to have a calendar pop-up only on clicking image available.

This is what i tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepick({
 showOn: 'button',
 buttonImage: 'calendar.gif',
 buttonImageOnly: true,
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 showAnim: 'slideDown',
 duration: 'fast'
});

});
</script>
```

What i want is to load calendar on `image` click and should not be focused when i have a cursor on `Textbox`

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFter all i got this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateofBirth').datepick({ showOnFocus: false, showTrigger: '#Img1' });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your imagebutton in a div or any other element with id and then call datepicker function like following

```
<tr><td>date</td><td><asp:textbox id="txtdate" runat="server"/></td>
<td id="dtpinvoker"><asp:imagebutton id="btn" runat="server" imageurl="your image"/></td></tr>


and then in your head section 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#dtpinvoker').datepick({
 showOn: 'button',
 buttonImage: 'calendar.gif',
 buttonImageOnly: true,
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 showAnim: 'slideDown',
 duration: 'fast'
});

});
</script>
```